# Should I answer a question that already has valid answers?

Tags: discussion

I was just recently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693032/convert-old-format-javascript-dictionary-to-key-value-format#25693032) question and had an answer worked out when I noticed it had already been answered (more than once). The answers all do the same thing and since the OP wasn't concerned about performance/efficiency/etc, just completing a task, I decided not to answer, though my answer was different than the ones posted (at the time).

This led me to wonder, if a question already has valid answers that should be/will be the accepted answer even if it hasn't been accepted yet, should I post another answer that's just a variation on what's already been provided? It may be different (technically), but doesn't really offer anything to the knowledge the question provides. The question has been answered and my answer isn't going to improve the situation at all, so I feel that putting another answer on there may just confuse the issue.

This particular question was fun to think about, which is why I think it received so many answers at once, but I also think that one or two answers showing a way to do it would be more than enough and any more is just clutter.

Or am I over thinking this?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The question has been answered and my answer isn't going to improve the situation at all

That's your answer right there.  If your answer is not *adding value* then you shouldn't be posting it.

If posting your answer is *adding value* and would actually be helpful to future readers, either because the answer is clearer, more generalized, more performant, etc. then by all means.  If you don't actually think it has anything to add though, then you're just creating noise.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks!

Comment: @Blunderfest There's also an edge-case between commenting on an existing answer / the question vs posting your own answer, if you add something valuable: Does it add enough (in your very own opinion) to standas an answer?

Comment: In this case, no. But I understand the distinction you make.